# Bluetooth not working with Atheros AR9462 chip on Utopic / 3.16 kernel

Tags: bluetooth, 14.10, atheros, ath9k

**Bluetooth not working with Atheros AR9462 chip on Utopic / 3.16 kernel**

I need assistance from the community, please. I seem to have stumbled upon a big issue with support for bluetooth on these Atheros chipsets. Unfortunately I have only a light grasp of what I am doing when I start working with kernel modules.

I purchased a Acer V3 Nitro laptop (VN7-791G-77HR) in December and installed Utopic Unicorn 14.10 x86_64. Laptop uses a Atheros AR9462 wifi/bt combo chipset.

Bluetooth is not working properly. I cannot detect any devices in pairing mode. Everything else is working fine including wifi. BT works fine in Windows 8.1 on this machine.

Gnome-bluetooth applet opens and seems to indicate the bluetooth is enabled. When I add a device it just searches for 30 seconds and then closes with no device ever found.

Here is output from hcitool and rfkill.

```
tkitz@LUAN:~$ hcitool dev
 Devices:
    hci0    38:B1:DB:76:F0:B8
tkitz@LUAN:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
tkitz@LUAN:~$
```

I installed dkms module and copied some '.dfu' files as listed in this linux-firmware [Bug # 1394368](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1394368)

Here is the output of dkms status showing the ar9462/1.5.1 module installed.

```
tkitz@LUAN:~$ sudo dkms status
[sudo] password for tkitz: 
ar9462, 1.5.1, 3.16.0-24-generic, x86_64: built
ar9462, 1.5.1, 3.16.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I am pretty much stuck at this point. Any help would be appreciated. If nothing else, I am sure I will learn a bit more about dkms and modprobe. :-)

Here is the output of **lsusb**. This is a PCI device so I am not sure what this tells us. (trying to understand the fundamentals)

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:2970 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0489:e076 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is the relevant output of **lshw**.

```
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 01
            serial: 38:b1:db:76:f0:b7
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.16.0-28-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
            resources: irq:18 memory:d1500000-d157ffff memory:d1580000-d158ffff
```

Here is the output of **hciconfig --all**:

```
tkitz@LUAN:~$ sudo hciconfig --all
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
   BD Address: 38:B1:DB:76:F0:B8  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
   UP RUNNING PSCAN 
   RX bytes:26817 acl:0 sco:0 events:4800 errors:0
   TX bytes:32459 acl:0 sco:0 commands:4009 errors:0
   Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0xd8 0x7f 0x7b 0x87
   Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
   Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
   Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
   Name: 'LUAN'
   Class: 0x7c0100
   Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
   Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
   HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x1102
   LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x1
   Manufacturer: Atheros Communications, Inc. (69)
```

Comment: Try to update the rpi this might help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Update the RPI? I do not know what you are referring to. rpi-update is for Raspberry Pi's. Do you mean "apt-get update"? I have upgraded all available packages if that is what you were referring to.

Comment: What is the result of `lsusb` in terminal

Comment: I added lsusb and lshw to the original post. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I would uninstall that dkms module as it doesn't list your device in ath3k.c or btusb.c
You could try this one that I modified to add your bluetooth ID to
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0mxc8g98abuoxcx/ar9462-dkms_2.0_all.deb?dl=0

If you see a firmware loading error in `dmesg | grep firmware` another few step need to be taken to help `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf` and then `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local` and above the line that says exit 0 add `modprobe ath3k` save exit program and reboot.  I even had to do the last steps in 14.10 to get bluetooth working on a consistent basis

Edit: download this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajxndivy4vwgapv/test.zip?dl=0 and extract it to /home so you have a folder named test in home, then in terminal `sudo apt-get install build-essential`

```
cd test
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make all
sudo dkms remove ar9462/2.0 --all
sudo dkms remove ar9462/1.5 --all
sudo modprobe -r ath3k
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname-r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko.bak
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r0/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko.bak
sudo cp ath3k.ko  /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo cp btusb.ko  /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
```

Reboot

```
modinfo ath3k | grep -i e076
```

If it displays a line with e076, it should work

Edit: I have learned that the firmware for this device is currently available only in windows drivers.  If you have dual boot with windows and the windows drivers installed, the firmware can be found in Program Files\Common Files\QCA_bluetooth

Comment: No luck. dkms module installed ok. ---------   tkitz@LUAN:~/Downloads$ sudo dkms status
ar9462, 2.0, 3.16.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

Comment: You might need to reboot and then check `dmesg | grep firmware` to see if any errors occured

Comment: I tried all that. Nothing listed for 'firmware' in dmesg buffer. I went ahead and blacklisted ath3k module then rebooted. No luck, same issue. hcitool shows bt device but cannot detect any remote devices to pair.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the results of `hciconfig --all` so I can see if it is the AR3012 device I think it is

Comment: Original post updated with output requested. thnx for sticking with this. Happy New Year!

Comment: Did that but now BT device is no longer detected. hcitool shows nothing. here is the output of modinfo. ---- `tkitz@LUAN:~$ modinfo ath3k | grep -i e076
alias:          usb:v0489pE076d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*`

Comment: With BT not detected run `dmesg | grep firmware`

Comment: dmesg shows firmware loading error. ---- `tkitz@LUAN:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   12.906848] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
<truncated>[   12.913250] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   18.598123] Bluetooth: Error in firmware loading err = -110,len = 448, size = 4096
[   18.598133] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
tkitz@LUAN:~$ `

Comment: If that is still with ath3k blacklisted and loaded with rc.local, you might try editing rc.local to include `sleep 20` above `modprobe ath3k`  Have you installed package linux-firmware? `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`

Comment: Did that, prepended 'sleep 20' to ath3k.conf and rebooted. same issue. BT firmware failed to load. I removed the blacklist  and rebooted again but no change. Yes, linux-firmware is installed.

Comment: sleep 20 should have been entered into /etc/rc.local above modprobe ath3k as I don't know if it will cause problems in /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf `cat /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf should contain only `blacklist ath3k` and the last lines of `cat /etc/rc.local` should be `sleep 20` `modprobe ath3k` `exit 0` on seperate lines

Comment: Oops. sorry. that makes more sense. I removed the sleep statement from ath3k.conf and added to rc.local above 'blacklist ath3k'. Rebooted. Same problem. BT firmware not loading (same error as above).

Comment: your /etc/rc.local contains blacklist ath3k?  /etc/rc.local should have modprobe ath3k and can you get me the model number off the wifi card, it might be printed on the bottom of the laptop

Comment: I made a mistake in my comment above. I meant to say 'before modprobe ath3k'.  ath3k.conf has blacklist statement. rc.local had modprobe ath3k.  Qualcom wifi card is QCNFA222. I never even thought to search the model of wifi card. I am learning something here. :-)

Comment: Well... I am done trying to get BT working on this Atheros card. I updated to the latest stable kernel, 3.18.1, to see if that would help. no go. I will try anything that you might have in the works but thank-you for all your help nonetheless. I did blacklist the ath3k module and now have my other BT adapter working perfectly. I learned a lot plus I got to listen to Blink-182 Greatest Hits album about 100x's on loop while banging away at this.

Comment: send an email to: ath9k-devel@lists.ath9k.org  Use topic add support for 0489:e076 and in the message include the result of `hciconfig --all` `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` and `sudo lspci -vnn` this should get the kernel developers involved in figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known bug, I got it too:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1352821